# Android:Invalidating Linear Layout doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I have an imageView inside of a LinearLayout and when I call invalidate on that LinearLayout it doesnt invalidate until the phone sleeps and wake again.

Is there anyway of forcing the LinearLayout to invalidate straight away?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by invalidating the view?

Comment: I am trying to add another imageview inside this linearLayout but it doesnt invalidate until i sleep the phone or press back to go back to the previous activity

Comment: You don't need to call invalidate if all you're doing is adding another view. Maybe you can post the code where you add the other ImageView

Comment: So basically i am reading in all images from a folder in the SD card and setting all them images to a ImageView and adding it to the linearlayout.

Comment: So my code does atm is first loads in all the images from the folder and sets each of the image to a imageview and adds it to the LinearLayout, then i will click a button which will delete one image from the folder and i want the same image which is deleted from that folder to be deleted in the linear layout so what ive done is called linearLayout.removeAllViews() and then called a method to read all the images from the folder and set each of the image to a Imageview and added them to the linear layout

Answer (score 0):

From android documentation about invalidate function

> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible,
>   onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the
>   future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI
>   thread, call postInvalidate().

Answer (score -1):

This is over 3 years old, so I'm not anticipating a response, but if you don't think your `LinearLayout` is invalidating because you're not getting any calls to `onDraw()`, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17595671/852795:

> By default all ViewGroup sub-classes do not call their `onDraw` method,
>   you should enable it by calling `setWillNotDraw(false)` [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29)

From the doc:

> By default, this flag is not set on View, but could be set on some
>   View subclasses such as ViewGroup. Typically, if you override
>   `onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)` you should clear this flag.

Try adding `setWillNotDraw(false);` to your LinearLayout.