# My onDraw() method is never called

Tags: android

My issue is that no matter what I do, no matter how many questions and answers I read through on the internet, I cant get a simple rectangle to draw on my android device screen. Let me rephrase that, it shows up on screen but it wont change. I cant get an animation to update. onDraw() never calls multiple times, just once on startup. why? Here is my view objects code:

```
package prospect_industries.es;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class TestView extends View {

    //Variables
    public static final int SIZE = 300;
    public float TOP = 0.0f;
    public float LEFT = 0.0f;
    public float RIGHT = 100f;
    public float BOTTOM = 100f;

    private Paint rectanglePaint;
    private RectF rect1;

    //Constructors
    public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(final Context context) {
        super(context, null, 0);
        init();
    }

    //View methods
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawRect(rect1, rectanglePaint);
        Log.i("test1", "in onDraw");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        final int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        final int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);
        setMeasuredDimension(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
        Log.i("test1", String.valueOf(chosenWidth));
        Log.i("test1",String.valueOf(chosenHeight));
    }

    //Class Methods
    private int chooseDimension(final int mode, final int size) {
        switch (mode) {
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                return size;
            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            default:
                return getDefaultDimension();
        }
    }

    private int getDefaultDimension() { return SIZE; }

    private void init(){
        requestFocus();
        rectanglePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        rectanglePaint.setColor(-1);
        rectanglePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        rect1 = new RectF(LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM);
    }

    public void update() {
        RIGHT += 10;
        BOTTOM += 10;
        rect1 = new RectF(LEFT, TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM);
        invalidate();
        Log.i("test1", "in update");
    }
}
```

Here is my main class which has a few methods for other things Im working on as well as a timer which calls the update() method inside of my test view object.

```
package prospect_industries.es;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean setup = false;
    public int waitDelay = 1000; //Milliseconds - currently 1 second
    private Timer checkTime;
    private TimerTask listen;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

    //Splashscreen
    private Timer splashScreen;
    private int waitTime = 3000; //3 seconds

    private GaugeView mGaugeView;
    private final Random RAND = new Random();
    private TestView testview;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        //mGaugeView = (GaugeView) findViewById(R.id.gauge_view);
        testview = (TestView) findViewById(R.id.test_view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //Timers
        //1 second wait tick
        checkTime = new Timer();
        checkTime.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        //mGaugeView.setTargetValue(RAND.nextInt(101));
                        testview.update();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, waitDelay);

        //Set splash screen wait timer
        splashScreen = new Timer();
        splashScreen.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
                    }
                });
                splashScreen.cancel();
            }
        }, waitTime);

        //set welcome screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(checkTime != null) {
            checkTime.cancel();
            stop();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.stop();
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    public double getAmplitude() {
        if (mRecorder != null)
            return  mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        else
            return 0;

    }

    public void checkSound(){
        if (mRecorder == null) {
            mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
            try {
                mRecorder.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mRecorder.start();
        }
    }

    private static class MainView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

        public MainView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
            surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, here is the xml layout file which loads in the test view object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#103681"
    tools:context="prospect_industries.es.MainActivity">

    <prospect_industries.es.TestView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/test_view"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have been looking all over stackExchange for hours but I cant fix my problem, onDraw is only called once and never again no matter what I do. Right now the rectangle should be expanding out but it isnt being redrawn.

Comment: The second and third constructor of `TestView`: `super(context, attrs);` instead of `this(context, attrs, 0);` and `super(context);` instead of `this(context, null, 0);`. I think so.

Comment: Instead of thinking about what isn't happening, check what is happening; use a few system.out.prints to see the flow of the code in the console. That way you might get an idea of where it is failing.

Comment: I am getting a single log print because the program runs onDraw once at instantiation and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you initialize the rectangle to be 1px wide and 1px tall and never resize it. You should be able to see 1 white pixel somewhere in the top left corner of your TestView.

Try changing the `rect1` size to 0,0,100,100 and see if the problem persists.

```
public static final float TOP = 0.0f;
public static final float LEFT = 0.0f;
public static final float RIGHT = 100.0f;
public static final float BOTTOM = 100.0f;
```

Comment: I feel almost ashamed that I did not notice that. Ive spent so long working with graphics and java that I should have seen this. My only accomplishment at this point is that I actually succeeded in posting a stackExhange question without a bunch of people saying how its answered elsewhere for once. Thank you! I guess sometimes we cant see whats right in front of us even when its staring us dead in the face.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Glad I could help :)

Comment: I actually still have one problem. I added a couple lines of code to check for a change in the rectangle drawing and my issue actually persists. onDraw is never called. I will update the Question with my changes. Basically I'm adding to the width and height of the rectangle and invalidating the image but the onDraw method still never runs.

Comment: @TravisDewitt in the current implementation the rect1 size is growing by 1px every second. Are you sure that onDraw() is not called or you just didn't notice the 1px difference?

Comment: I have a log that prints every time the onDraw is called and it only prints once at startup. Also, I changed the change to 10px changes and still nothing happened.

Comment: I've tested your code on a Nvidia Shield( Android version 5.1.1) and it works just fine...just a wild guess - try `invalidate();requestLayout();`.

Comment: I feel so stuck. That didnt work. I'm on a galaxy note 4 and it just doesnt run.

Comment: Have you tried adding `setWillNotDraw(false);` inside your `init();` method? [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595546/why-ondraw-is-not-called-after-invalidate).

Comment: I have, I believe that is used in view groups more commonly anyway.