# Android custom view, onDraw not called after calling invalidate()

Tags: android, view, ondraw, invalidation

I'm using a custom view which doesn't call onDraw, or dispatchDraw when I call invalidate.

I called setWillNotDraw(false); in the constructor as told in this answer [Why onDraw is not called after invalidate()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595546/why-ondraw-is-not-called-after-invalidate)

But that doesn't change anything, still onDraw is not called.

I tried to call invlidate() on the super view, but still no luck.

I'm stuck, thanks for your help.

```
package com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress;

import common.utils.Debug;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by bruce on 14-10-30.
 */
public class DonutProgress extends View {
    private Paint finishedPaint;
    private Paint unfinishedPaint;
    private Paint innerCirclePaint;
    protected Paint textPaint;
    protected Paint innerBottomTextPaint;

    private RectF finishedOuterRect = new RectF();
    private RectF unfinishedOuterRect = new RectF();

    private float textSize;
    private int textColor;
    private int innerBottomTextColor;
    private int progress = 0;
    private int max;
    private int finishedStrokeColor;
    private int unfinishedStrokeColor;
    private int startingDegree;
    private float finishedStrokeWidth;
    private float unfinishedStrokeWidth;
    private int innerBackgroundColor;
    private String prefixText = "";
    private String suffixText = "%";
    private String text = null;
    private float innerBottomTextSize;
    private String innerBottomText;
    private float innerBottomTextHeight;

    private final float default_stroke_width;
    private final int default_finished_color = Color.rgb(66, 145, 241);
    private final int default_unfinished_color = Color.rgb(204, 204, 204);
    private final int default_text_color = Color.rgb(66, 145, 241);
    private final int default_inner_bottom_text_color = Color.rgb(66, 145, 241);
    private final int default_inner_background_color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
    private final int default_max = 100;
    private final int default_startingDegree = 0;
    private final float default_text_size;
    private final float default_inner_bottom_text_size;
    private final int min_size;


    private static final String INSTANCE_STATE = "saved_instance";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR = "text_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE = "text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_TEXT = "text";
    private static final String INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE = "inner_bottom_text_size";
    private static final String INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT = "inner_bottom_text";
    private static final String INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_COLOR = "inner_bottom_text_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "finished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "unfinished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_MAX = "max";
    private static final String INSTANCE_PROGRESS = "progress";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX = "suffix";
    private static final String INSTANCE_PREFIX = "prefix";
    private static final String INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_WIDTH = "finished_stroke_width";
    private static final String INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_WIDTH = "unfinished_stroke_width";
    private static final String INSTANCE_BACKGROUND_COLOR = "inner_background_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_STARTING_DEGREE = "starting_degree";

    public DonutProgress(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public DonutProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public DonutProgress(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        default_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 18);
        min_size = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 100);
        default_stroke_width = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 10);
        default_inner_bottom_text_size = Utils.sp2px(getResources(), 18);

        /*
        final TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DonutProgress, defStyleAttr, 0);
        initByAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.recycle();
        */
        initByAttributes(null);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        initPainters();


    }

    protected void initPainters() {
        textPaint = new TextPaint();
        textPaint.setColor(textColor);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        innerBottomTextPaint = new TextPaint();
        innerBottomTextPaint.setColor(innerBottomTextColor);
        innerBottomTextPaint.setTextSize(innerBottomTextSize);
        innerBottomTextPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        finishedPaint = new Paint();
        finishedPaint.setColor(finishedStrokeColor);
        finishedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        finishedPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        finishedPaint.setStrokeWidth(finishedStrokeWidth);

        unfinishedPaint = new Paint();
        unfinishedPaint.setColor(unfinishedStrokeColor);
        unfinishedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        unfinishedPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        unfinishedPaint.setStrokeWidth(unfinishedStrokeWidth);

        innerCirclePaint = new Paint();
        innerCirclePaint.setColor(innerBackgroundColor);
        innerCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    protected void initByAttributes(TypedArray attributes) {
        finishedStrokeColor = default_finished_color;
        unfinishedStrokeColor = default_unfinished_color;
        textColor = default_text_color;
        textSize = default_text_size;

        setMax(default_max);
        setProgress(0);
        finishedStrokeWidth = default_stroke_width;
        unfinishedStrokeWidth = default_stroke_width;

        innerBackgroundColor = default_inner_background_color;

        innerBottomTextSize = default_inner_bottom_text_size;
        innerBottomTextColor = default_inner_bottom_text_color;
        innerBottomText = "";

        startingDegree = default_startingDegree;
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        initPainters();
        super.invalidate();
    }

    public float getFinishedStrokeWidth() {
        return finishedStrokeWidth;
    }

    public void setFinishedStrokeWidth(float finishedStrokeWidth) {
        this.finishedStrokeWidth = finishedStrokeWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getUnfinishedStrokeWidth() {
        return unfinishedStrokeWidth;
    }

    public void setUnfinishedStrokeWidth(float unfinishedStrokeWidth) {
        this.unfinishedStrokeWidth = unfinishedStrokeWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    private float getProgressAngle() {
        return getProgress() / (float) max * 360f;
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        Debug.log("Donut", "progress="+progress);
        if (this.progress > getMax()) {
            this.progress %= getMax();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        if (max > 0) {
            this.max = max;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public float getTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }

    public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getTextColor() {
        return textColor;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getFinishedStrokeColor() {
        return finishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setFinishedStrokeColor(int finishedStrokeColor) {
        this.finishedStrokeColor = finishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnfinishedStrokeColor() {
        return unfinishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setUnfinishedStrokeColor(int unfinishedStrokeColor) {
        this.unfinishedStrokeColor = unfinishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getSuffixText() {
        return suffixText;
    }

    public void setSuffixText(String suffixText) {
        this.suffixText = suffixText;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public String getPrefixText() {
        return prefixText;
    }

    public void setPrefixText(String prefixText) {
        this.prefixText = prefixText;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getInnerBackgroundColor() {
        return innerBackgroundColor;
    }

    public void setInnerBackgroundColor(int innerBackgroundColor) {
        this.innerBackgroundColor = innerBackgroundColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }


    public String getInnerBottomText() {
        return innerBottomText;
    }

    public void setInnerBottomText(String innerBottomText) {
        this.innerBottomText = innerBottomText;
        this.invalidate();
    }


    public float getInnerBottomTextSize() {
        return innerBottomTextSize;
    }

    public void setInnerBottomTextSize(float innerBottomTextSize) {
        this.innerBottomTextSize = innerBottomTextSize;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getInnerBottomTextColor() {
        return innerBottomTextColor;
    }

    public void setInnerBottomTextColor(int innerBottomTextColor) {
        this.innerBottomTextColor = innerBottomTextColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getStartingDegree() {
        return startingDegree;
    }

    public void setStartingDegree(int startingDegree) {
        this.startingDegree = startingDegree;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(measure(widthMeasureSpec), measure(heightMeasureSpec));

        //TODO calculate inner circle height and then position bottom text at the bottom (3/4)
        innerBottomTextHeight = getHeight() - (getHeight()*3) /4 ;
    }

    private int measure(int measureSpec){
        int result;
        int mode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int size = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
        if(mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY){
            result = size;
        }else{
            result = min_size;
            if(mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST){
                result = Math.min(result, size);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        float delta = Math.max(finishedStrokeWidth, unfinishedStrokeWidth);
        finishedOuterRect.set(delta,
                delta,
                getWidth() - delta,
                getHeight() - delta);
        unfinishedOuterRect.set(delta,
                delta,
                getWidth() - delta,
                getHeight() - delta);

        float innerCircleRadius = (getWidth() - Math.min(finishedStrokeWidth, unfinishedStrokeWidth) + Math.abs(finishedStrokeWidth - unfinishedStrokeWidth)) / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, innerCircleRadius, innerCirclePaint);
        canvas.drawArc(finishedOuterRect, getStartingDegree(), getProgressAngle(), false, finishedPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(unfinishedOuterRect, getStartingDegree() + getProgressAngle(), 360 - getProgressAngle(), false, unfinishedPaint);

        String text = this.text != null ? this.text : prefixText + progress + suffixText;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            float textHeight = textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent();
            canvas.drawText(text, (getWidth() - textPaint.measureText(text)) / 2.0f, (getWidth() - textHeight) / 2.0f, textPaint);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getInnerBottomText())) {
            innerBottomTextPaint.setTextSize(innerBottomTextSize);
            float bottomTextBaseline = getHeight() - innerBottomTextHeight - (textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2;
            canvas.drawText(getInnerBottomText(), (getWidth() - innerBottomTextPaint.measureText(getInnerBottomText())) / 2.0f, bottomTextBaseline, innerBottomTextPaint);
        }

    }

    /*
    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

        float delta = Math.max(finishedStrokeWidth, unfinishedStrokeWidth);
        finishedOuterRect.set(delta,
                delta,
                getWidth() - delta,
                getHeight() - delta);
        unfinishedOuterRect.set(delta,
                delta,
                getWidth() - delta,
                getHeight() - delta);

        float innerCircleRadius = (getWidth() - Math.min(finishedStrokeWidth, unfinishedStrokeWidth) + Math.abs(finishedStrokeWidth - unfinishedStrokeWidth)) / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, innerCircleRadius, innerCirclePaint);
        canvas.drawArc(finishedOuterRect, getStartingDegree(), getProgressAngle(), false, finishedPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(unfinishedOuterRect, getStartingDegree() + getProgressAngle(), 360 - getProgressAngle(), false, unfinishedPaint);

        String text = this.text != null ? this.text : prefixText + progress + suffixText;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            float textHeight = textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent();
            canvas.drawText(text, (getWidth() - textPaint.measureText(text)) / 2.0f, (getWidth() - textHeight) / 2.0f, textPaint);
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(getInnerBottomText())) {
            innerBottomTextPaint.setTextSize(innerBottomTextSize);
            float bottomTextBaseline = getHeight() - innerBottomTextHeight - (textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2;
            canvas.drawText(getInnerBottomText(), (getWidth() - innerBottomTextPaint.measureText(getInnerBottomText())) / 2.0f, bottomTextBaseline, innerBottomTextPaint);
        }
    }
    */

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR, getTextColor());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE, getTextSize());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE, getInnerBottomTextSize());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_COLOR, getInnerBottomTextColor());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT, getInnerBottomText());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_COLOR, getInnerBottomTextColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getFinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getUnfinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_MAX, getMax());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_STARTING_DEGREE, getStartingDegree());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_PROGRESS, getProgress());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_SUFFIX, getSuffixText());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_PREFIX, getPrefixText());
        bundle.putString(INSTANCE_TEXT, getText());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_WIDTH, getFinishedStrokeWidth());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_WIDTH, getUnfinishedStrokeWidth());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_BACKGROUND_COLOR, getInnerBackgroundColor());
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if(state instanceof Bundle) {
            final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            textColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_TEXT_COLOR);
            textSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_TEXT_SIZE);
            innerBottomTextSize = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_SIZE);
            innerBottomText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT);
            innerBottomTextColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_INNER_BOTTOM_TEXT_COLOR);
            finishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            unfinishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            finishedStrokeWidth = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_WIDTH);
            unfinishedStrokeWidth = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_WIDTH);
            innerBackgroundColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
            initPainters();
            setMax(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_MAX));
            setStartingDegree(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_STARTING_DEGREE));
            setProgress(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_PROGRESS));
            prefixText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_PREFIX);
            suffixText = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_SUFFIX);
            text = bundle.getString(INSTANCE_TEXT);
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE));
            return;
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: blind guess: you do not understand the main(UI) thread and using `DonutProgress.setProgress` in some loop on main thread ... which will obviously not work as OS "has no time" to redraw the view between `setProgress` calls

Comment: Thx you were right, I just called setProgress in runOnUiThread, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The call to setProgress was done in a timer loop, which is not the ui thread. I used runOnUiThread like this to make it work.

```
MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                mProgress.setProgress(0);
        }
});
```