# Refreshing custom view every second after cclicking button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, view

I created Linear Layout with two custom views.

```
class myView1(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
...
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?){..}
}

class myView2(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : View(context, attrs) {
...
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?){..}
}
```

I have button. I would like to have situation like this:

- If button clicked: start loop which will be calling onDraw every second (refreshing View every second)
- If button clicked once again: break the loop.

I was trying by .invalidate(), but it didn't work.

How can I call create that loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't write a comment, so I will answer, you didn’t write exactly how it doesn’t work `invalidate()` method, [invalidate() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595546/why-ondraw-is-not-called-after-invalidate),
in any case, I added a loop where you need to call `invalidate()`

```
  var timer = Timer()
            var isTimerWork = false
    
            btn.setOnClickListener {
                if (isTimerWork) {
                    isTimerWork = false
    
                    timer.cancel()
                    timer = Timer()
                } else {
                    isTimerWork = true
    
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(object : TimerTask() {
                        override fun run() {
    //                       invalidate view
                        }
                    }, 0, 1000)
                }
            }
```